# SQL Join Issues with 2 Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have TABLE A with FIELD1 with codes such as 145, 156, 167 etc and I have FIELD2 with the same codes. In table B - I have codes and locations such as

```
145   Birmingham 
156   Boise 
167   Raleigh
```

I want to display the locations for FIELD1 and FIELD 2 but am having problem with the JOIN...

```
SELECT 
    a.FIELD1, b.ID, b.LOCATION, a.FIELD2
FROM 
    TABLE A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN    
    TABLE B b ON a.FIELD1 = b.ID;
```

I can see the Location description for FIELD1 - but how do I retrieve the Location description for FIELD2 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join table B twice:

```
SELECT 
    a.FIELD1, 
    b1.ID as ID1,
    b1.LOCATION as Location1,
    a.FIELD2, 
    b2.ID as ID2, 
    b2.Location as Location2
FROM TABLEA a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB b1 ON a.FIELD1 = b1.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB b2 ON a.FIELD2 = b2.ID;
```